# h:outputLink with f:ajax - method called, but link not shown

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, facelets

This does not work

```
<h:form style="display: inline;">
    <h:outputLink value="#{title.link}" >
        #{msg['g.readMore']}
        <f:ajax event="click" immediate="true" listener="#{titlesBean.titleClicked(title.id)}" />
    </h:outputLink>
</h:form>
```

What I want it to do is when clicked to call `#{titlesBean.titleClicked(title.id)}` and then go to the link. The method is called but it doesn't go to the link. There are several other ways to do it (with commandLink and then a redirect, but I would like to know why this is not working).

This is the method itself:

```
public String titleClicked(long titleId) {
    this.titlesManager.addXtoRating(titleId, 1);
    return null;
}
```

**Note**: this is only a sidenote, but I accidentally found out that this works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.share').popupWindow({centerBrowser:1,height:380,width:550});
</script>

<h:form style="display: inline;">
    <h:outputLink styleClass="share" value="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php...">
        <img src="images/facebook-icon.jpg" />
        <f:ajax event="click" immediate="true" listener="#{titlesBean.titleLiked(title.id)}" />
    </h:outputLink>
 </h:form>
```

Check out the `styleClass="share"`

**Update**: (I have less than 100 rep, so I cannot answer my own question for 8 hours, this is how to put it delicately - stupid).
I waited for a while, but nobody answered.

So this is my hacked solution ( I don't like it at all, but it works):

```
<h:form style="display: inline;">
    <h:outputLink target="_blank" styleClass="click8" value="#{title.link}" >
        #{title.heading}
        <f:ajax event="click" immediate="true" listener="#{titlesBean.titleLiked(title.id)}" />
    </h:outputLink>
</h:form>
```

And this is the important part:

```
<h:head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.click8').click(function (event){
                         var url = $(this).attr("href");
                         window.open(url, "_blank");
                         event.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
</h:head>
```

Note: this has to be in the header, otherwise I had a major bug with the link opening a thousand windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not work because there's means of a race condition here. Two HTTP requests are been sent simultaneously in the same window. One ajax to the server and one normal to the given link. The one which finishes sooner wins. You want to send the HTTP requests in sync. First the ajax one to the server and when it returns, **then** the normal one to the given link.

As to your hacky solution, it works because it uses JavaScript to open the URL in a new window instead of the current one and then blocks the link's default action, so the normal response just arrives in a completely separate window while the ajax response still arrives in the initial window. So there's no means of a race condition of two HTTP requests in the initial window anymore.

As to the final solution, this is not possible with standard set of JSF 2.0 components. Using `<h:commandLink>` and then doing a redirect is indeed doable, but the link is this way not crawlable by searchbots and it fires effectively a POST request, which is IMO more worse than your new window solution.

If you would really like to open the link in the current window, hereby keeping the target URL in the link's href, then I'd suggest to create a simple [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) which does the link tracking and redirecting job and let jQuery manipulate the link target during `onclick`.

Something like this

```html
<a rel="ext" id="ext_#{title.id}" href="#{title.link}">read more</a>
```

*(HTML element IDs may not start with a digit! Hence the `ext_` prefix, you can of course change this whatever way you want.)*

with

```
$(function() {
    jQuery('a[rel=ext]').click(function(e) {
        var link = jQuery(this);
        var url = 'track'
            + '?id=' + encodeURIComponent(link.attr('id')) 
            + '&url=' + encodeURIComponent(link.attr('href'));

        if (link.attr('target') == '_blank') {
            window.open(url);
        } else {
            window.location = url;
        }

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

and

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/track"})
public class TrackServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB
    private TrackService trackService;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String id = request.getParameter("id");
        String url = request.getParameter("url");

        if (id == null || url == null) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
            return;
        }

        trackService.track(id.replaceAll("\\D+", "")); // Strips non-digits.
        response.sendRedirect(url);
    }

}
```

Comment: I thought of the race condition but didn't have to knowledge to fix it.

Comment: Also I thought of the servlet solution - I think google search has some similar mechanism. But refused to believe that this is the only option.

Comment: Btw, thank you for the really extensive answer. Still, is there a way to do all that without a tracking servlet with pure javascript? I would like to make one request to the server for tracking and the response to be ignored and then another request for the actual link. And would like all this to work even when the user does Ctrl+Click on the link. I don't know if all that is possible at all with javascript.

Comment: Send one request with the second URL as request parameter and let the server side redirect to it. This is only not SEO friendly.

Comment: This way I will not be able to open it in a new window. And I have to have `target="_blank"`

Comment: So the requirement is to open it in a new window? Just add `target="_blank"` then? I don't see how that forms a problem.

Comment: In some of the cases, yes. Unfortunately not in all of them.